# iAd banner in Share Extension?

Tags: ios, iad, ios8-share-extension

Is it possible to show iAd banners in a share extension?

I'm using `canDisplayBannerAds` rather than adding an `AdBannerView` in the storyboards in the main app & share extension - this all works fine in the app, but I'm not seeing anyting in the extension.

Has anyone had any success with this, or is it just not possible using `canDisplayBannerAds`?

Comment: Is it possible, yes. You could add your `ADBannerView` to your share extensions view controller. I don't think it can be achieved using `canDisplayBannerAds` though. Creating the `ADBannerView` programmatically would be required. Would I suggest doing this, no. Let the user focus on sharing the contents of your app. The chance of a potential new customer because of a shared post outweighs the need for one more iAd impression for me.

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately the app in questions is ad supported, and all its key features are available in the share extension!

Comment: I see. If you'd like to add your code showing how you create your share extension to your question, I'll work on adding a `ADBannerView` to it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm fine with adding an a banner. In fact I replaced the code to do just that with `canDisplayBannerAds` hoping for a short cut. Looks like it's back to the old way.